# Parse.com and Facebook login, runs infinite loop

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, facebook-login, parse-platform

I updated both Parse and Facebook iOS SDKs to the latest versions, and when I try to login using Facebook my app crashes, and from the debugger I can see that it is calling 3-4 methods in an endless loop.

My login code looks like this:

```
- (void)openSession
{
    UIViewController *topViewController = self.window.rootViewController;
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_likes", @"friends_likes", nil];

    // Login PFUser using Facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
            }
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");

            if ([[topViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[PALoginViewController class]]) {
                [topViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
            if ([[topViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[PALoginViewController class]]) {
                [topViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

The error occurs when `logInWithPermissions` is called. It crashes into Xcode and Debugger is showing an awful lot of calls to FB login methods - thousands actually:

[image: Stack trace]

What could be wrong?

Comment: This is happening to me as well. I filed this bug: 

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/188127071335876?browse=search_517585c69d75e2752804242

Comment: @Skotch Yeah, I found your bug report today. Curious to see how fast they'll deal with it.

Comment: Also see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/16135087/facebook-sdk-3-5-cant-log-in-crashes-app . We found a problem server side that should be addressed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was reported as a bug on Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/188127071335876?browse=search_5176d24c698df3761093726

It has now been fixed, and I can confirm that logging in now works - even with Sandbox enabled.

Comment: There is still an issue here in that the SDK will crash your app if there is any sort of server error, including your device not having connectivity. 

I filed this: 

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/446010282155033

On another thread, Facebook says they are on the remaining infinite loop crash issue.

Comment: Doh! Quite a few bad mistakes in this release, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox off, then it should works.

Comment: Happening to me and I do not have sandboxing turned on. Sandboxing should be valid in any event, and should not cause an infinite loop.

Comment: This actually worked for me! But yes, sandboxing should be valid and not differ in behavior.

Comment: Yes I thought so, anyway curious to know which answer would be replied.

Comment: @Skotch You got this with sandbox disabled?

Comment: @Piotr Now this problem is solved from 3.5.1. Thanks MartinHN