# Facebook iOS SDK 3.5 login issue

Tags: facebook, crash, facebook-login

I've already integrated facebook login in an app with the previous sdk version. After upgrading to version 3.5, it isn't working. When I want to login, the app crashes, with several [FBSession authorizeWithPermissions:defaultAudience....] callings in the thread.
I've already done all the steps described in Upgrading documentation. Somebody with the same problem?
Thanks in advance.

The app is for iOS.

Comment: I think I have the same problem, see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118314/parse-com-and-facebook-login-runs-infinite-loop

Comment: Exact the same problem. If you find something useful, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Are you presenting the login viewcontroller in a modal, like I do?

Comment: I think, that doesn't matter. I've found that the problem is a reported bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/188127071335876?browse=search_5174e73fbe3965769089278

Comment: Same thing happening to me. I did notice that if I got rid of FacebookDisplayName the problem goes away, but that doesn't seem correct. I think it is just covering up the real problem. 

I reported bug also: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/188127071335876

Comment: As an answer to my questions states, turning off sandbox mode worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16153697/2972

Comment: Also see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/16135087/facebook-sdk-3-5-cant-log-in-crashes-app . There was a problem server-side that we found and has been addressed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set Sandbox Mode to disabled.  This will fix this problem for now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has fixed part of the problem on the server side. Try it again and it will probably work for you.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/188127071335876?browse=search_51770009e1ec62f68874486

This was a server error that was causing this for a lot of developers. However, the server fix only makes the infinite loop problem less likely to happen. It is still there. I created a new bug to track the infinite loop problem.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/446010282155033